# How to handle html onKeyPress() event in playframework with parameters?

Tags: playframework-2.0

I am trying to build an online editor using play frame work. However I am stuck at the very beginning. My requirement is to start a scala function in the controller every time user presses a key in the text area taking the key pressed as an argument.

My body part should be some thing like this.

```
<body>        
   </div>

           <textarea onKeyPress="(This should redirect to foo.scala in controller along with key pressed as parameter )"> </textarea>
   </div>
</body>
```

How to handle the onkeypress() event in play framework?

Comment: How can we guess what the `???parameter???` is?

Comment: As I mentioned in the question Its the key pressed on the text area

Answer (score 0):

`onKeyPress` could be a JavaScript function which makes a request to your backend with the pressedKey as argument. Think AJAX

```
<textarea onkeypress="myFunction(event)"></textarea>

<script>
function myFunction(event) {
   var chCode = ('charCode' in event) ? event.charCode : event.keyCode;
   alert ("The Unicode character code is: " + chCode);

   /* make an HTTP request here */
}
</script>
```

In your `routes` file you can have something like:

```
POST    /events/:ch      controllers.Application.handleEvent(ch: Integer)
```